# Changing Image depending on Twitch channel is live or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Alright, so basically I want to change an image when a channel goes live. Here is the HTML I am using

```
<img src="img/portfolio/knarf.png" class="img-responsive" class="2twitch2" href="http://www.twitch.tv/NotKnarf" data-tnick="notknarf">
```

And the JQuery that I made

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('.2twitch2').each(function () {
    var tnick = $(this).data('tnick');
    var span = $(this).next();
    $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + tnick + ".json?callback=?", function (c) {
        if (c.stream == null) {
            var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("live.png", ".png");
            $(this).attr("src", src);
        } else {
            var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "live.png";
            $(this).attr("src", src);
        }
    });
});
```

});

I am just trying to get it to add live.png on the end. I thought this would work, but I am just getting the same image, like it isn't changing anything when it goes live.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the JSON request URL is correct? When I try https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/[username].json?callback=?, I get a bad request; just https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/[username] seems to work, though.

Comment: I am using the .json?callback=? to make it look just for whether the stream is online or not, it isn't really grabbing the link, it is just letting the code know to look for a certain thing. Instead, I set it to just look for the stream "online" or "null" and return that. api.twitch.tv/karaken/streams/[username] returns a lot of useless garbage :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare the `class` attribute only once in your `img`:

`<img src="img/portfolio/knarf.png" class="img-responsive 2twitch2" href=`...

Comment: It's still not changing on live :/

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Does it get `c.stream` correctly? Or is it just not changing the `img` `src`?